# C# Generic Constraint - How to refer to current class type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public abstract class AbstractBasePresenter<T> : IPresenter<T> 
    where T : class, IView
{
}

public interface IPresenter<T>
{
}

public interface IView<TV, TE, TP> : IView
    where TV : IViewModel
    where TE : IEditModel
    //where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<???>
{
}

public interface IView {}
```

Is there any way that I can constrain TP on IView<> to be a class that inherits from AbstractBasePresenter?

Or is my only alternative to create a non-generic IPresenter interface and then update IPresenter to implement it and then use check "TP : IPresenter"?

Thanks

Update:

Proposed answer below does not work:

```
public interface IView<TV, TE, TP> : IView
where TV : IViewModel
where TE : IEditModel
where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<IView<TV,TE,TP>>
{
}
```

I have interface declared as:

```
public interface IInsuredDetailsView : IView<InsuredDetailsViewModel, InsuredDetailsEditModel, IInsuredDetailsPresenter>
{ }

public interface IInsuredDetailsPresenter : IPresenter<IInsuredDetailsView>
{ }
```

Compiler complains that IInsuredDetailsPresenter is not assignable to AbstractBasePresenter>

Comment: `AbstractBasePresenter` with what `T`? C# has no concept of instances of generic types for which some type parameters have not been set.

Comment: `where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<IView<TV,TE,TP>>` compiles but I'm not sure that it will provide the result what you want...

Comment: As a remark, the following structure is overcomplicated and it is hard to understand what it can be useful for.

Comment: See my edited answer. You may prefer to constrain your `TP` to `IPresenter<T>` instead

Comment: In your original question you wanted TP constrained to AbstractBasePresenter, which is a class. Your interface, IInsuredDetailsPresenter does not (and cannot) inherit from a class (AbstractBasePresenter). You need to change your constraint so that TP is constrained to IPresenter<IView<TV, TE, TP>> if you do not require TP to inherit from AbstractBasePresenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but you need to provide one more type argument to the `IView<>` interface:

```
public interface IView<TV, TE, TP, T> : IView
    where TV : IViewModel
    where TE : IEditModel
    where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<T>
    where T : class, IView
{
}
```

**Edit:**

According to editions in your question: `IInsuredDetailsPresenter` is definitely not assignable to `AbstractBasePresenter`. Compiler is complaining due to the constraint you requested in your original question. More specifically due to this part

```
where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<T>
```

It seems you want to constrain `TP` to be an interface as well. You may try the below piece of code:

```
public interface IView<TV, TE, TP, T> : IView
    where TV : IViewModel
    where TE : IEditModel
    where TP : IPresenter<T>
{
}
```

Constraints on `T` are no more needed, because `IPresenter<T>` has none. Of course, you could adapt armen.shimoon's answer in a similar manner. The point is to replace `AbstractBasePresenter<T>` constraint with `IPresenter<T>` constraint.

Comment: Your code does not compile. You are missing a `where T : IView`

Comment: I don't think you need to add the fourth generic parameter.

Comment: @armen.shimoon: depends on what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

No problem, no need for another generic parameter:

```
public interface IView<TV, TE, TP> : IView
    where TV : IViewModel
    where TE : IEditModel
    where TP : AbstractBasePresenter<IView<TV,TE,TP>>
{
}
```

Edit: Updated question:

If you do not need the presenter to inherit from AbstractBasePresenter, change the code to:

```
public interface IView<TV, TE, TP> : IView
    where TV : IViewModel
    where TE : IEditModel
    where TP : IPresenter<IView<TV,TE,TP>>
{
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good given that strongly-typed support to the fullest is not needed. (You have no control of what type exactly is the `T` in `AbstractBasePresenter`.)